Conda Errors after ```conda update -n base -c defaults conda```
I get geting the error fter any conda command were it goes:
Error while loading conda entry point: anaconda-cloud-auth (cannot import name 'ChannelAuthBase' from 'conda.plugins.types' ({condaPath}\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\conda\plugins\types.py))

AND
Error while loading conda entry point: anaconda-cloud-auth (cannot import name 'ChannelAuthBase' from 'conda.plugins.types' (---\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\conda\plugins\types.py))
Error while loading conda entry point: anaconda-cloud-auth (cannot import name 'ChannelAuthBase' from 'conda.plugins.types' (---\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\conda\plugins\types.py))
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: unsuccessful initial attempt using frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Solving environment: unsuccessful attempt using repodata from current_repodata.json, retrying with next repodata source.
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: unsuccessful initial attempt using frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.

CONDA IS NOT UPDATED running conda --version GIVES:
Error while loading conda entry point: anaconda-cloud-auth (cannot import name 'ChannelAuthBase' from 'conda.plugins.types' (----\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\conda\plugins\types.py))
Error while loading conda entry point: anaconda-cloud-auth (cannot import name 'ChannelAuthBase' from 'conda.plugins.types' (----\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\conda\plugins\types.py))
conda 23.7.4

This error happened after running the command conda update -n base -c defaults conda
Ran it because i got Warning:
==> WARNING: A newer version of conda exists. <==
  current version: 23.7.4
  latest version: 24.3.0

Please update conda by running

    $ conda update -n base -c defaults conda

Or to minimize the number of packages updated during conda update use

     conda install conda=24.3.0

Running on Windows 11, conda V 23.7.4

See https://stackoverflow.com/q/78347799/3862372

You can try to use
conda install conda=24.3.0 

directly to solve the problem. I solved the problem using this method.
Thank you for your question, which gave me ideas to solve the problem.
