When using conda command, terminal keeps showing "Error while loading conda entry point: anaconda-cloud-auth" & failed in updating conda with command
When using conda command, terminalkeeps showing "Error while loading conda entry point: anaconda-cloud-auth".I tried conda update conda, but it doesn't work.And I found that my conda couldn't update.My conda staied in 23.7.x(I don't remember exactly).
I tried to remove anaconda-cloud-auth. Then I found my conda updated to 23.11.0. And the error report was gone. I used conda install anaconda-cloud-auth, and it succeeded with 0 error. But, I found the newest conda editions start with 24.x.x, and I tried conda update conda again, it still staied in 23.11.0.

It seems a bug related to this appeared recently and is affecting many Conda and Mamba users; I am experiencing it with Mamba. See this related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78347799/why-my-anaconda-keeps-showing-error-while-loading-conda-entry-point (the reinstallation solution posted there fails for me). Also see this Conda community thread: https://community.anaconda.cloud/t/issue-updating-anaconda-cant-open/70182. Hopefully a solution will appear in one of these places soon.

Here is the official solution：
python -m pip uninstall anaconda-cloud-auth
conda update conda
conda install “anaconda-cloud-auth>0.5.0”

If you use Anaconda Navigator:
conda update anaconda-navigator


I had same error
cannot import name 'ChannelAuthBase' from 'conda.plugins.types'
conda update conda
Error while loading conda entry point: anaconda-cloud-auth (cannot import name 'ChannelAuthBase' from 'conda.plugins.types' (C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\conda\plugins\types.py)) Error while loading conda entry point: anaconda-cloud-auth (cannot import name 'ChannelAuthBase' from 'conda.plugins.types' (C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\conda\plugins\types.py))
I tried to update conda but it broke down and started giving more error. I tried to uninstall and then install cloud auth but that did not work.
I also referred the solution over here
https://community.anaconda.cloud/t/issue-updating-anaconda-cant-open/70182
But it did not work for me.
I uninstalled anaconda cleared all the cache files restarted the system and then installed. Now it is working fine for me.

I actually came from here to this question:
https://community.anaconda.cloud/t/issue-updating-anaconda-cant-open/70182
Unfortunatedly they used the wrong quotation marks, so you get an PackagesNotFoundError for "“anaconda-cloud-auth"
You have to type (use "..." insted of “...”):
python -m pip uninstall anaconda-cloud-auth
conda update conda
conda install "anaconda-cloud-auth>0.5.0"

